# I'm getting an error 400 on xsr.send in my ajax call in .NET Core

Tags: jquery, ajax, .net-core

I'm getting an error 400 on an Ajax call that I'm trying to make in .NET core 2.0 with entity framework using jQuery 2.2.

My Controller Method looks like this:

```
[HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public JsonResult RetrieveDateCollections(string CollectionDate)
    {
        ViewData["CollectionTypeId"] = new SelectList(_context.Set<CollectionType>(), "CollectionTypeId", "CollectionTypeDescription");
        ViewData["MemberId"] = new SelectList(_context.Member, "MemberId", "FullName");

        var sPCC_Context = _context.Collection.Include(c => c.CollectionType).Include(c => c.Member);
        return Json(sPCC_Context.ToListAsync());
    }
```

And My JavaScript as Follows:

```
function RetrieveDateCollections() {
    var collectionDate = $('#CollectionDate').val().toString();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: "/Collections/RetrieveDateCollections",
        timeout: 40000,
        data: JSON.stringify({ "CollectionDate": "12/10/2018" }),
        dataType: "json",
        done: function (data) {
            alert("Success: " + response.toString());
        },
        fail: function (Result) {
            alert("Error: " + Result.statusCode);
        }
    });
}
```

And I'm calling it from my view like so:

```
<input type="date" asp-for="CollectionDate" class="form-control" onblur="RetrieveDateCollections();" />
```

I wind up with the following error:

[In Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/svCaA.jpg)

When you drill down the offending line seems to be:

```
xhr.send( options.hasContent && options.data || null );
```

Any ideas?

Comment: what are the values for options.hasContent and options.data? do they hold the values that you expect?

Comment: That line of code I from the JQuery library. I wouldn't know what it's supposed to do. And I haven't gotten as far as being able to get information into my method using the "data" parameter. For now I've been using QueryString. I get into the method though.

Comment: so in your serverside method (mvc) wrap it in a try catch block  and see what gets onto the catch statement. Also if it's getting to the method, what line causes the error when you step. I also suspect you just need to `return Json(sPCC_Context);`

Comment: Ok. So an update. It only gets to the method when I remove "[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]". But then I get the error: "RetrieveDateCollections Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET". Also, no exception is being thrown in the method itself.

Comment: After implementing the code below, I still get the connection reset error. The error in IE is "XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x2eff, Could not complete the operation due to error 00002eff." Not sure if that helps.

Comment: @Ebarreto as you mentioned the problem with the formatting is caused by ```.Include()``` extension at least for me. If you try this ```var sPCC_Context = _context.Collection;``` it will work. I'm also trying to find a solution to this. Please Let me know if you found a workaround.

Comment: @Ebarreto Actually found the solution here https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/5910. Just need to edit ```services.AddMvc()``` to ```services.AddMvc().AddJsonOptions(x => x.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore)``` in the the startup.cs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code can't validate the antiforgery-token (because your aren't sending it).

Either you remove the `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]` tag in your controller OR you add a way to retrieve the antiforgery-token in your javascript and post it. the simplest way to do that is to modify your JS in this way:

```
function RetrieveDateCollections() {
    var collectionDate = $('#CollectionDate').val().toString();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: "/Collections/RetrieveDateCollections",
        timeout: 40000,
        headers: { "RequestVerificationToken": getAntiforgeryToken() },
        data: JSON.stringify({ "CollectionDate": "12/10/2018" }),
        dataType: "json",
        done: function (data) {
            alert("Success: " + response.toString());
        },
        fail: function (Result) {
            alert("Error: " + Result.statusCode);
        }
    });
}

function getAntiforgeryToken() {
    // get the token from the form and return it
    var token = $('input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val();
    return token;
}
```

For this to work you need to include an antiforgery-token in your view, as such:

```
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
```

Comment: After implementing the code above, I still get the connection reset error. The error in IE is "XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x2eff, Could not complete the operation due to error 00002eff." Not sure if that helps.

Comment: Update: Final resolution was two fold. The code above helped get rid of the 400 error leaving me with the connection one. The connection was being reset because apparently the data being returned from the server side method was either too much and in the wrong format. I replaced "return Json(sPCC_Context.ToListAsync());" with "return Json("{'CollectionDate': '12 / 10 / 2018'}" );" and the call completed. Now to work on getting the data in the right format. Thanks all!

Comment: @Ebarreto as you mentioned the problem with the formatting is caused by ```.Include()``` extension at least for me. If you try this ```var sPCC_Context = _context.Collection;``` it will work.  I'm also trying to find a solution to this. Please Let me know if you found a workaround.

Comment: It worked for me when I added `@Html.AntiForgeryToken()` on view/csthtml page. Including below code in ajax request.
               `beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                    xhr.setRequestHeader("XSRF-TOKEN",
                        $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val());
                },                
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                data: JSON.stringify(datas),`